# Can someone help me remove muiltple returns of this function making it have only a single return?

Tags: python, computer-science

I wrote this code and after I finished it completely, then I realized from the requirements that it says that the code must have one return. I have been trying to change it and fix it to have one return but I keep getting errors and I don't know why.

**functions**:

```
def is_valid(name):       
   if len(name) == 0:   
       return False

   if not (name[0].isalpha() or name[0] == '_'):
       return False                               

   if len(name) > 1:
       for char in name[1:]:  
           if not (char.isalnum() or char == '_'):   
               return False                     
   return True
```

**t01.py:**

```
print("var:", is_valid("var"))
print("var2:", is_valid("var2"))
print("2var", is_valid("2var"))
print("var?", is_valid("var?"))
print("camelCase:", is_valid("camelCase"))
```

**The question:**

```
Write and test the following function:

def is_valid(name):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Determines if name is a valid Python variable name.
    Variables names must start with a letter or an underscore.
    The rest of the variable name may consist of letters, numbers
    and underscores.
    Use: valid = is_valid(name)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        name - a string to test as a Python variable name (str)
    Returns:
        valid - True if name is a valid Python variable name,
            False otherwise (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
Add this function to the PyDev module functions.py. Test it from t01.py.
```

**Sample results:**

```
var : True
var2 : True
2var : False
var? : False
camelCase : True
```

Comment: if your code is working and you just want to improve it, you should post to [Code Review Site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: This can be solved with regular expressions. Something like `[A-Za-z_][\dA-Za-z_]*` (this is untested and there's probably an easier way to write this, but this should be functional: https://regex101.com/r/EgZN0c/1)

Comment: For me, you code works... You say that you have some errors. Can you give more details?

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is to set a `result` variable:

```
def is_valid(name):
   result = True
       
   if len(name) == 0:   
       result = False

   elif not (name[0].isalpha() or name[0] == '_'):
       result = False                               

   elif len(name) > 1:
       for char in name[1:]:  
           if not (char.isalnum() or char == '_'):   
               result = False
       
   return result
```

It appears that you simply want to check that the name starts with a letter or underscore, and that the rest is alphanumeric (or underscores).  You can wrap that logic into an `any` or `all` operation.

```
if all(char.isalnum() or char == '_' for char in name[1:]) ...
```

And that lets you handle the entire check in a single statement ... if you find that readable:

```
return name and \
       (name[0].isalpha() or name[0] == '_') and \
       all(char.isalnum() or char == '_' for char in name[1:])
```

Comment: this seems quite inefficient - previously it would `return` early in case it would match the condition, now it can loop several times needlessly in the third `if`. At least add `break` there.

Comment: Should probably make those into `elif`s with the change since unlike the original, this will throw an error on `name = ''`

Comment: Right; I was taking this one step at a time.  I'll do it your way instead of mine.  :-)